# Replace select tag with a check box to toggle between dark and light theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `select` tag with jquery to toggle between dark and light themes for website appearance.

This is my code which is working fine.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.style-change').change(function() {

    var style = $(this).val();
    $('body').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr("href", style + ".css");
      $('body').fadeIn("slow");

      $.cookie("css", style, {
        expires: 365,
        path: '/'
      });
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#style").val('<?php echo $style; ?>');
});
```

```html
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['css'])) {
    $style = $_COOKIE['css'];
} else {
    $style = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min';
}
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $style; ?>.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select name="" class="style-change form-control" id="style">
      <option value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min">Default Style</option>
      <option value="https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min">Night Mode</option>
    </select>
  </body>

  </html>
```

I want to use a checkbox to toggle between themes/stylesheets instead of `select` tag.

#### Update

I update this snippet which is working as per my requirements

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var theme = '<?php echo $style; ?>';
        if (theme == 'https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min') {
            $("#style").prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("#style").prop('checked', false);
        }
        $('#style').click(function() {
            var style = this.checked ? 'https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min' : 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min';
            $('body').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr("href", style + ".css");
                $('body').fadeIn("slow");

                $.cookie("css", style, {
                    expires: 365,
                    path: '/'
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['css'])) {
    $style = $_COOKIE['css'];
} else {
    $style = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min';
}
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $style; ?>.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="style">
      <label>Dark Theme</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="style">
      <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: `$('#btnSumbit')` should be `$('#btnSubmit')`.

Comment: on selection of a particular field what do you want background color ti be changed as you said them????

Comment: I set default bootstrap style and want checkbox is checked and submitted then dark stylesheet should be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one mistake `$('#btnSumbit')` should be `$('#btnSubmit')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#style').click(function() {

        var style = this.checked ? 'https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min' : 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min';

        $('body').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr("href", style + ".css");
            $('body').fadeIn("slow");

        });

    });
    
    var defaulttheme = 'https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min';
if(defaulttheme == 'https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min'){
$('#style').attr("checked",true); //do when you just want to update checked status
$('#style').click();
//do when you want to set initial theme to dark


}
});
```

```html
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['css'])) {
    $style = $_COOKIE['css'];
} else {
    $style = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min';
}
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $style; ?>.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="style">
      <label>Dark Theme</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="style">
      <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: the function is running but new stylesheet is not applying.

Comment: I am seeing in first snippet that you are appending `https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min` css for black theme but not doing in second snippet, I updated my code just check now.

Comment: How can I revert back to the default theme?       Can I achieve this without submit button only on checking and unchecking of the checkbox?  I ask this because I want to design checkbox and make this like a  toggle switch

Comment: Updated check now.

Comment: Thanks. how can I add or remove `checked` based on stylesheet?

Comment: I think you are looking for initial default theme right? If yes then I updated my code for this check.

Comment: I want which stylesheet selected in cookies. checkbox `checked` or `unchecked` based on that. Mean when default stylesheet saved in cookies then the checkbox is `unchecked` but when dark stylesheet selected in cookies then the checkbox is initially `checked` on page load

Comment: Ok I did same above just replace your style from cookies in `defaulttheme`  variable

Comment: I did this but not work. Can you update `code snippet`.

Comment: Use `$('#style').click();` instead `$('#style').attr("checked",true);` I mentioned usage of these two above in code comment

Comment: Can you update you second snippet with latest code ?

Comment: I updated the second `snippet` which works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding a value to the checkbox

```
<input id="#input" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

and then do something like this

```
if($("#input").value == "true"){
   applyDarkTheme();

}else{
   applyLightTheme();
```

}

Comment: can you how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use a checkbox to toggle between themes/stylesheets

Yes its possible:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dark').on('change', function() {
    var href = 'https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-indigo.css';
    if (this.checked) {
      href = 'https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css';
    }
    $('<link>', {
      'href': href,
      'rel': 'stylesheet'
    }).appendTo('body');
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id='lbl'><input id='dark' type="checkbox"/>Use Dark Theme</label>

<div class="w3-card-4">
  <div class="w3-container w3-theme w3-card">
    <h1>Indigo</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-container w3-text-theme">
    <h2>w3-text-theme</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference [site](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_color_themes.asp)